# React native TextInput Autofocus is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I am having two screens in react native app say Screen A Screen B.
A textinput is present in Screen A. I have put autofocus true for that and its working initially.

When we navigate from screen A to Screen B , and then navigates back from B-> A, then the textinput autofocus is not working.

Do any one have any soultion for this ??

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.textInput}
  textStyle={styles.inputTextStyle}
  autoFocus={true}
  placeholder='Enter Code'
  keyboard={'numeric'}
  placeholderTextColor={AppStyles.color.grey}
  value={code}
  onChangeText={this.updateCode}
  underline={false}
/>
```

Comment: This link may help: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/. For anyone wondering how to listen for when the screen navigates back to A from B. The `useFocusEffect` hook could be used.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `autofocus` triggers first time on `componentDidMount`. To trigger it manually after navigating back from B to A, you've to use `withNavigationFocus` HOC. So when the user focuses screen A, you can use following code to show keyboard.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class FocusStateLabel extends React.Component {
   componentDidUpdate() {
       if(this.props.isFocused){
           this.inputField.focus();
       }
   }  
   render() {
     return (
       <TextInput
         ref={(input) => { this.inputField = input; }}
         placeholder = "inputField"
       />
     )
  }
}

// withNavigationFocus returns a component that wraps FocusStateLabel and passes
// in the navigation prop
export default withNavigationFocus(FocusStateLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

The AutoFocus props is only fired when the component is mounted. When you are navigating back to A, if A is still mounted (just hidden), then the autofocus will not work again.

You should use a ref (add a new state, `ref` here for example), and add a handler, on navigate back from B to A, to fire `this.state.ref.focus()`

```js
<TextInput
          ref={ref => ref && this.setState({ref})}
          style={styles.textInput}
          textStyle={styles.inputTextStyle}
          autoFocus={true}
          placeholder='Enter Code'
          keyboard={'numeric'}
          placeholderTextColor={AppStyles.color.grey}
          value={code}
          onChangeText={this.updateCode}
          underline={false}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jarret's comment (withNavigationFocus is deprecated with V6) and this StackOverflow answer ([Can't focus TextInput when navigating to a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138351/cant-focus-textinput-when-navigating-to-a-screen)):

```
import {useFocusEffect} from 'react-navigation/native';

const TestFocus = (props) => {

  const textRef = useRef(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
     // When the screen is focused
     const focus = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
       textRef?.current?.focus();
      }, 1);
     };
     focus();
     return focus; // cleanup
    }, []),
  );


  return (
   <TextInput
     ref={textRef}
   />
  )
  
}
```