# Can't focus TextInput when navigating to a screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-paper

I have a react-native-paper TextInput that I want to focus automatically when I navigate to a screen (using react-native-navigation). I have tried setting `autoFocus={true}` on the TextInput, but that didn't work.

In another attempt, I tried to focus it manually by listening to the 'focus' event on the screen, but that only focused it the first time I opened the screen. Is there any way of getting it to work reliably?

```js
export default function NewAccountScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const textInputRef = createRef();

  // This isn't working, neither is autoFocus...
  const focusOnInput = () => {
    textInputRef.current?.focus();
  }

  navigation.addListener("focus", focusOnInput);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput ref={textInputRef} label="Account name" value={name} onChangeText={setName}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: `autoFocus={true}` is now working as of Aug 2023.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `React.useRef()` instead of createRef();
use `React.useEffect` to listen when `ref` is defined to can use it.

```js
export default function NewAccountScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const textInputRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
     if(textInputRef.current){
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
          textInputRef.current?.focus()
        });
       return unsubscribe;
     }
  }, [navigation, textInputRef.current]);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput ref={textInputRef} label="Account name" value={name} onChangeText={setName}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

#### Update: as @pta2002 comment

> I tried this, and it focuses sometimes now, but sometimes it seems to focus and then immediatelly unfocus...

i test the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pta2002/0745da), and as he said it is already not working in some times!
Really I can't understand why?, but I try something, and it is work.

#### listen for `transitionEnd` not `focus`

try snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/autofocus-bug-demo?platform=android)

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (textInputRef.current) {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('transitionEnd', () => {
        textInputRef.current?.focus();
      })

      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, [navigation, textInputRef.current])
```

other solution work for me surround `textInputRef.current?.focus();` with setTimeout with 1000 ms

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (textInputRef.current) {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
           textInputRef.current?.focus();
        }, 1000);
      })

      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, [navigation, textInputRef.current])
```

Comment: I tried this, and it focuses sometimes now, but sometimes it seems to focus and then immediatelly unfocus...

Comment: if you can add more code or create snack with the problem, please do.

Comment: Hm I rewrote the code here: https://snack.expo.dev/@pta2002/0745da and now it works... Guess I'll just use this

Comment: I honestly have no idea why it does not work, I copy-pasted this code into my app and it still does not work. I guess it must be something elsewhere

Comment: Update: I tried the same expo again, and this time it did not work, so I guess there's something wrong here still. Seems like it's something that only happens on the android version though.