# React native TextInput Autofocus unstable

Tags: react-native

react-native: 0.65.1

I'm trying to open keyboard when Modal is opened (by autofocusing TextInput inside it)

- Firstly I tried with autoFocus prop and it absolutely works on ios, and Android in DEV mod (Android in Prod mod fully ignore this prop)
- To fix android I tried solution with ref.focus() inside componentDidUpdate (useEffect in my case) [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861091/10534856), but it is ignored too

Then I tried to run .focus() inside setInterval (in code example), and it started to work (but not each time when I open a Modal).

Also my TextInput is inside Modal:

```
import {Modal} from 'react-native';
```

Question: Is it a bug with TextInput component? And Is there any more stable solutions with autoFocus, or maybe another way to open keyboard with screen opening?

````
import {TextInput} from "react-native";

export const Input: React.FC = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused.current && inputRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
      }, 0);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => {
        isFocused.current = true;
      }
    );
    return () => {
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <TextInput value={'MOCK VALUE!'} ref={inputRef} autoFocus/> // autoFocus useLess for android here
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add dependency array in the first useEffect.

```
import {TextInput} from "react-native";

export const Input: React.FC = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused.current && inputRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
      }, 0);
    }
  },[]); // add dependency array here

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => {
        isFocused.current = true;
      }
    );
    return () => {
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <TextInput value={'MOCK VALUE!'} ref={inputRef} autoFocus/> // autoFocus useLess for android here
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I want to run code inside useEffect by every render, so should use useEffect without deps.

Comment: Always add dependency array.